# Why doesn't comparing arrays in componentDidUpdate lead to infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lifecycle

I have this code in my pure component:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { scheduleSheet } = this.props;
    const { scheduleSheet: prevScheduleSheet } = prevProps;

    if (scheduleSheet !== prevScheduleSheet) {
      this.setState({ board: scheduleSheet });
    }
  }
```

Since arrays are objects in JS, the `scheduleSheet !== prevScheduleSheet` will always turn out to be `true`. Why doesn't component get stuck in a infinite loop of updates then? I mean, every time 'componentDidUpdate' runs, it will see that prevProps is not equal to new ones, so it will update the state, which will run `componentDidUpdate`... so why doesn't that happen?

---

And example of `this.props.scheduleSheet` (which refers to the state of the parent component):

```
[
  null,
  null,
  [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    true
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    true
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    true
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    true
  ]
]
```

Comment: can you show how your this.props looks like ?

Comment: @CodeManiac added. `this.props.scheduleSheet` refers to the state property of the parent component`

Comment: Show us how you pass the props, why do you expect the diff reference

Comment: @Skypho this is strange it should not happen with the code you have posted on question, there may be something else which is causing this issue can you post a codepen or create a minimum runnable snippet to reproduce the problem

Comment: You can check the example I shared in codesandbox and see if it answers your question.

Comment: The props are not equal first and then after the render they point to the same array, if only the state changes. Updated the code in codesandbox. Check it out and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

How you pass the `props`?

```
const DEFAULT_SHEET = [];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Component scheduleSheet={DEFAULT_SHEET} />
  }
}

class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { scheduleSheet } = this.props;
    const { scheduleSheet: prevScheduleSheet } = prevProps;

    // Always false because the reference (props) never change.
    if (scheduleSheet !== prevScheduleSheet) {
      this.setState({ board: scheduleSheet });
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above, the reference doesn't change, therefore `scheduleSheet !== prevScheduleSheet` expression is always `false` and won't cause inifite loop due to "logic" reasons.

---

Moreover, you using `React.PureComponent` therefore in such situation you won't get an infinite loop:

```
                     // v NOT PURE COMPONENT, causes infinite loop and crash
class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { scheduleSheet } = this.props;
    const { scheduleSheet: prevScheduleSheet } = prevProps;

    console.log('scheduleSheet', scheduleSheet);
    console.log('prevScheduleSheet', prevScheduleSheet);
    this.setState({ board: prevScheduleSheet });
  }

  onChange = e => this.setState({ board: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexBox>
        <Input value={this.state.board} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </FlexBox>
    );
  }
}
```

That's because of [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) implements `shouldComponentUpdate` with shallow prop and state comparison, which prevents the "unnecessery render".

[image: Edit Q-57873953-PureComponent,ComponentDidUpdate]

Comment: You're wrong about that. PureComponent or Component doesn't matter. You can check the example I shared and change it accordingly to check.

Comment: Your example is under the "logic" reason as I explained, remove the if statement and see what happens. https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hoover-swkm2

Comment: Actually, you are right. I was always assuming there was an if statement.

Comment: Can you edit the answer, I'll upvote it. And yours is the correct answer.

Answer (score -3):

**EDIT:**
I got the question wrong, assumed that the code has `if (scheduleSheet !== prevScheduleSheet) {`

Dennis's answer above is correct.

---

When you do this

```
if (scheduleSheet !== prevScheduleSheet) {
      this.setState({ board: scheduleSheet });
    }
```

The props are different in the first render, but then after the state update the props point to the same array, since only state changes.
You can see that clearly from the below example.

---

Objects and arrays are shallow compared and this messes up with the updates sometimes but when the props don't change, the array is the same, unless you update the props using a new array with the same value everytime.

Checkout this example:

[image: Edit awesome-hofstadter-vw1sf]

**UPDATE:**
You can uncomment the code in componentDidUpdate and see the inifite loop vs why it won't when the props don't change.